# Player and computer try to remove 1-3 until number reaches 0. How to make sure computer wins everytime?

Tags: python-3.x

```html
import random as r
numb = r.randint(20,30)
mylist = [1,2,3]
print('starting number:', numb)
while True:
    playerremove = int(input('How many do you want to remove? must be 1-3'))
    numb -= playerremove
    print(numb, 'left')
    if numb <= 0:
        print('Computer wins')
        break

    #compremove = r.randint(1,3)
    if numb <=4:
      for i in range(2,5):
        if numb == i:
          compremove = i-1
    if numb <= 9:
      for i in range(4,8):
        if numb == i:
          compremove = i-1
    else:
      compremove = r.randint(1,3)
    

    numb -= compremove
    print('computer removes', compremove)
    print(numb, 'left')
    if numb <= 0:
        print('You win')
        break
```

This is a python programming challenge extension in my school. I want to extend it so that the computer would basically guarantee to win.

Task Instructions:
Original Number is between 20-30.
The player and the computer can remove 1,2, or 3 from the number in turns.
The player or computer who has to remove the last value that would bring the number down to zero is the loser.

My above programme could guarantee a victory for the computer but the computer doesn't remove between (1-3). How would I make it so that the computer wins while only removing in range 1-3?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ask yourself how to win if the number is 5.   https://www.cartalk.com/radio/puzzler/playing-cards-ray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a recursive problem. To see the win conditions we can start from the simplest case, that is a player brings the number down to `1`. The only choice for the other player now is `1` as well and hence they will loose. Conversely, if we bring the number to any of `(2, 3, 4)` the other player has the oppurtunity to bring it down to `1` and we loose. Hence we can summarize so far: bringing the number down to ...

- ... `1` results in a win.
- ... any of `(2, 3, 4)` results in a defeat.

From that follows if we bring the number to `5` then the other player has to bring it to any of `(2, 3, 4)` and we win again. `(6, 7, 8)` results in a defeat for similar reasons as above. More generally we can say that the winning numbers are (the number after we made our choice):

```
[1 + i for i in range(0, start_value, 3)]
```

That means in order to win a player needs to hit the next winning number with their choice, if possible. Note that if the current number is already a winning number this won't be possible though. Hence the optimal choice is:

```
max_choice = 3
choice = (current_value - 1) % (max_choice + 1)
choice = max(choice, 1)
```

The last line `choice = max(choice, 1)` is required since if the `current_value` is already a winning number the optimal choice will result in `0` but that is forbidden by game rules; in this case it doesn't matter what number is chosen, the other player now has the opportunity to win.

Following the above arguments, there is no definitive winning strategy for the computer if the starting number is randomly chosen in the range `(20, 30)` since if it's one of `(21, 25, 29)` the computer necessarily reaches a non-winning number, no matter the choice.

Comment: I've tested this code, but it didn't really work, is it alright if you could write the entire code because I'm not entirely sure where to add in the new lines of codes you suggested.

Comment: @Victor10 Just replace the whole part that computes `compremove` with the following: `compremove = (numb - 1) % 4 or 1`.